# How can I set the target Android SDK for Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, build, sdk

For a new Cordova project, I want to add Android as a platform using

```
cordova platform add android
```

And I want to use Android version 16. So I set these properties in the `config.xml`

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

And I run

```
cordova platform add android --target android-16
```

Yet what I see in the logging is

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: io.cordova.hellocordova
        Name: HelloCordova
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-26
```

So it still targets Android 26 instead of 16. Indeed, when I run `cordova build`, it builds using Android version 26. Why is that? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you use to provide android version is wrong.

Instead of

> cordova platform add android --target android-16

it should be

```
cordova platform add android@16
```

Comment: Those version numbers indicate the Cordova version used for the android platform, right? So android@16 does not even exist. For example android@5.1 does, and that will install Android target version 23. Is there a way to set the target Android SDK version directly?